# ADAL node js username password authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, adal, adal.js

I am using the adal node js library 1.22, and trying to authenticate a user with username and password. I am getting a "unable to get local issuer certificate" error. The user is federated and the error happens on realm discovery.

```
 var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword(resource, sampleParameters.username, sampleParameters.password, sampleParameters.clientId, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```

The error stack:

```
Stack:
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
{ Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY' }
Wed, 14 Jun 2017 08:44:17 GMT:079c7b70-6ae1-461c-b433-cc3fe0c22783 - TokenRequest: VERBOSE: getTokenFunc returned with err
well that didn't work: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
```

Can you please advise on what certificate i am missing and where to find it.

**EDIT**

after digging through the code i found that commenting out the global agent.ca part of the code resolved this issue and the library was able to perform a few steps after that, but it had a problem returning the token response from ADFS.

The log:

```
    Wed, 14 Jun 2017 10:39:39 GMT:425e3117-a495-4f8e-8a12-e7e64dd0e37b - OAuth2Client: INFO: Get TokenServer returned this correlationId: 425e3117-a495-4f8e-8a12-e7e64dd0e37b
Wed, 14 Jun 2017 10:39:39 GMT:425e3117-a495-4f8e-8a12-e7e64dd0e37b - OAuth2Client: ERROR: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.\r\nTrace ID: aadf1560-18ec-46f9-83b6-5932c2131200\r\nCorrelation ID: 425e3117-a495-4f8e-8a12-e7e64dd0e37b\r\nTimestamp: 2017-06-14 10:39:41Z","error_codes":[70002],"timestamp":"2017-06-14 10:39:41Z","trace_id":"aadf1560-18ec-46f9-83b6-5932c2131200","correlation_id":"425e3117-a495-4f8e-8a12-e7e64dd0e37b"}
```

Is there any configuration that i forgot,

```
if (!parametersFile) {
  sampleParameters = {
    tenant : 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com',
    authorityHostUrl : 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
    clientId : 'aa461028-1fgf-46e5-ab9b-5adca324febc',
    username : 'user@domain.net',
    password : 'lamepassword'
  };
}

var authorityUrl = sampleParameters.authorityHostUrl + '/' + sampleParameters.tenant;

var resource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000';
```

Answer (score 2):

**The resource owner flow is strongly discouraged, and in some cases like federated users or users that require MFA, will just not work.** This flow is the one in which your application handles the user's username and password directly and sends those in the request to the identity provider. This approach won't work if there are any extra interactions required as part of authentication such as requiring a second factor or dealing with federation. For these reasons and simple security principles (removing the need for the application to deal with the username and password) it's better to avoid this flow.

Since you are dealing with federated users, the resource owner won't work for you leaving you with the two preferred alternatives:

- **Use the [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code) if you want to authenticate as a user**
- **Use the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) if you want to authenticate as an application**.

See the ["Web Application to Web API" scenario in the "Azure AD Authentication Scenarios" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api) for more information about choosing between these two options.

Comment: I done see anywhere in the ADAL sample, where the username and password is sent using "authorization code flow"?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Which ADAL sample? Samples that showcase the authorization code flow don't handle usernames and passwords. Unless you are dealing with a sample that shows the resource owner flow, you won't see the app handling the username and password.

Comment: Is the resource owner flow still not supported for federated users? I have tried it now and it seems to work fortunately. At least the verbose log shows `AccountType: federated`...